# keeping checked checkbox state until user unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Currently, when moving page, I want to keep status of checkbox which I checked in the previous page.
I also tried my self and looked up on the internet.
I found some solution for this but it's not good.
The below is sample I found but it only worrk on Firefox, not in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Persist checkboxes</title>
<style>
button {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label> <input type="checkbox"
        id="option1">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label> <input type="checkbox"
        id="option2">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="option3">Option 3</label> <input type="checkbox"
        id="option3">
</div>
<button>Check all</button>



<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function handleButtonClick(button) {
        if ($(button).text().match("Check all")) {
            $(":checkbox").prop("checked", true)
        } else {
            $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false)
        }
        ;
        updateButtonStatus();
    }

    function updateButtonStatus() {
        var allChecked = $(":checkbox").length === $(":checkbox:checked").length;
        $("button").text(allChecked ? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
    }

    function updateCookie() {
        var elementValues = {};
        $(":checkbox").each(function() {
            elementValues[this.id] = this.checked;
        });

        elementValues["buttonText"] = $("button").text();
        $.cookie('elementValues', elementValues, {
            expires : 7,
            path : '/'
        })
    }

    function repopulateFormELements() {
        var elementValues = $.cookie('elementValues');
        if (elementValues) {
            Object.keys(elementValues).forEach(function(element) {
                var checked = elementValues[element];
                $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
            });

            $("button").text(elementValues["buttonText"])
        }
    }

    $(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
        updateButtonStatus();
        updateCookie();
    });

    $("button").on("click", function() {
        handleButtonClick(this);
        updateCookie();
    });

    $.cookie.json = true;
    repopulateFormELements();
</script>
```

Please tell me know the way to do in this case.
Thanks

Comment: what is your question? are you looking for http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is working in firefox just because firefox remembers the state of the form inputs.
If you want it to work in all browsers, you can use cookies to stock the checked/unchecked values or use rather localStorage (new in html5) used to store key => value pairs only

You'd want to put onchange listeners on all checkboxes and store the value (checked/unchecked) in LS.

```
var all_inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < all_inputs.length; i++)
{
     if( all_inputs[i].getAttribute("type") == "checkbox")
     {
         checkbox = all_inputs[i];
         checkbox.addEventListener("change", function()
         {
             localStorage.setItem(checkbox.getAttribute("name"), ""+checkbox.checked ); // To convert boolean to string i put "" + checkbox.checked
         }
     }
}
```

But we also have to change checkboxes states at the loading of the page if we have states saved in local storage.

```
var all_inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
document.onload = function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < all_inputs.length; i++)
    {
         if( all_inputs[i].getAttribute("type") == "checkbox")
         {
             checkbox = all_inputs[i];
             if( (var value = localStorage.getItem(checkbox.getAttribute("name")) != null)
             {
                 if(value == "true")
                     checkbox.checked = true;
                 else if(value == "false")
                     checkbox.checked = false;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

**EDIT : So the entire code to include in a script tag would be :**

```
document.onload = function()
{
    var all_inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    document.onload = function()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < all_inputs.length; i++)
        {
             if( all_inputs[i].getAttribute("type") == "checkbox")
             {
                 checkbox = all_inputs[i];

                 // Change the state (checked/unchecked) if the state is saved in localStorage 
                 if( (var value = localStorage.getItem(checkbox.getAttribute("name")) != null)
                 {
                     if(value == "true")
                         checkbox.checked = true;
                     else if(value == "false")
                         checkbox.checked = false;
                 }

                 // Then put onchange listeners to notify when checkbox state changes in order to save the state in the localStorage
                 checkbox.addEventListener("change", function()
                 {
                     localStorage.setItem(checkbox.getAttribute("name"), ""+checkbox.checked ); // I used : "" + checkbox.checked to convert boolean to string
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you modifiy something ?